# goodFeaturesToTrack() works only on greyscale?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new to working in openCV. I was trying to detect features in an image using goodFeaturesToTrack() in c++ in a colored image but it gave me the following error:

**" OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.type() == CV_8UC1 || src.type() == CV_32FC1) in cv::cornerEigenValsVecs, file D:\cs436\opencv-3.2.0\modules\imgproc\src\corner.cpp, line 287 "**

Then I tried it on a greyscale image and it found the features. Can anyone please tell if we can use the function on a colored image? and what does the error mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [`goodFeaturesToTrack()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga1d6bb77486c8f92d79c8793ad995d541), the `image` parameters takes in a 8-bit or 32-bit single channel image. single channel implies grayscale.

So yes, the function only works for grayscale images. The error message also indicates that by saying that the src.type() must have 1 channel as indicated by CV_8U**C1** and CV_32F**C1**

Comment: Okay i got it. But im trying to make a panorama so could you suggest some other feature detector i could use? or any work around to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That right the function is defined for grayscale images only. To apply colored images you have to convert the rgb image to a grayscaled image by:

```
cv::cvtColor(rgbImage, grayImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

Comment: Thankyou sir. 
Im trying to make a panorama so could you suggest some other feature detector i could use? or any work around to the problem.

Comment: You can use the goodFeaturesToTrack but use the grayImage as described above for the input of this function and do the stiching with th rgbImage

Comment: im really sorry to bother you but could you tell me how to include the following library:
**#include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"**
virtual studio says it cannot open the source file, though i have given the path to all the dll's thus it might mean that i dont have it with the installed version.

Comment: have you configured the include paths in your vs solution correctly?

Comment: yes. The problem was that i was using opencv 3.2 so the include for the non free section was now different. Thankyou very much.